# AngularJS not adding new property to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following Javascript code (on AngularJS controller):

```
$scope.schedule = {}

$scope.selectEquipment = function(equip) {
    //alert(equip);
    $scope.schedule.equipment = equip;
}
```

I receive well the equip, but when I try to add a property to $scope.schedule doesn't create. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you know it doesn't create the property? is it not outputting what you expect? are you getting an error?  there isn't enough information here to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I use AngularJS chrome Add-On and see it on scope

Comment: Sorry, aparently I was mistaken by the AddOn. I printed the property after afected and is saved

Comment: yea this should work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.schedule = {}

$scope.selectEquipment = function(equip) {
    console.log(equip); // Check Chrome Console
    $scope.schedule.equipment = equip;
    console.log($scope.schedule); // Check Chrome Console
}
```

Check the console in Chrome Dev Tools to actually see if `schedule` is being set.